# Time Data Does Not Match Format Python Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, runtime-error

I am trying to get the amount of days between the date the user selects from today's day. I get this error when attempting to run it:

```
raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '1/28/21' does not match format '%m %d %y'
```

I am very new to python, so any help pointing me in the right direction is very much appreciated!

```
# Import Required Library
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import Calendar
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.today()

# Create Object
root = Tk()

# Set geometry
root.geometry("500x800")

# Add Entry Box for token goal amount
instructions1 = Label(text="Please input your goal amount for the pay period.")
instructions1.pack(pady=10)

tokenGoal = Entry(root)
tokenGoal.pack(pady=10)

instructions2 = Label(text="Please enter the amount you currently have")
instructions2.pack(pady=10)

tokenAmount = Entry(root)
tokenAmount.pack(pady=10)

instructions3 = Label(text=today)
instructions3.pack()

print(today)

# Add Calender
cal = Calendar(root, selectmode='day',
               month=1, day=22,
               year=2021)

cal.pack(pady=20)


def grad_date():
    date.config(text="Selected Date is: " + cal.get_date())
    find_days_left()


def find_days_left():
    selected_date = datetime.strptime(cal.get_date(), '%m %d  %y')
    days_left = selected_date - today
    instructions3.config(text=today)


# Add Button and Label
Button(root, text="Calculate Pay Period",
       command=grad_date).pack(pady=20)

date = Label(root, text="")
date.pack(pady=20)

# Excecute Tkinter
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @mlwn Well I cannot justify the downvotes, but the error isnt formatted properly. New users are supposed to read how to ask a question, but I don't think anyone would(even me). Also the error is simple and cased by typo, OP should research properly before asking simpler questions too.

Comment: I admit, I didn't read about formatting errors, I will be sure to look that up for future questions. I do appreciate the help I was given for sure!

Comment: @mlwn My guess is the downvote was because questions that result from code with typos are not considered good or useful, because the point of SO is not necessarily to answer a question, but to create a repository of "good" questions and answers, that others can use as a resource. Questions with issues caused by typos are typically closed and deleted. Typos should be called out in a comment. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Trenton McKinney Interesting, well I definitely didn't understand the true purpose of stack overflow, thank you for sending me that link. Where can I go to ask questions such as the one above? I don't think I will ever have a question that is unique enough for stack overflow, but the help I received here was very valuable.

Comment: You can always ask a question, but it may or may not be well received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error appears to be here:

```
    selected_date = datetime.strptime(cal.get_date(), '%m %d  %y')
    days_left = selected_date - today
    instructions3.config(text=today)
```

The date format is should be `"%m/%d/%y"`
Notice the slashes separating the values rather than spaces.

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple, I've been banging my head over this for a couple hours now! Thank you!!

Comment: The littlest things are the hardest to catch. Try this sometime, its pretty effective: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this, if this is what you want..

```
   f_date = date(2005, 11, 7)
   l_date = date(2021, 3, 13)
   delta = (l_date - f_date)
   print(delta.days)}
```